# React: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<body>
  <script>
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  </script>
</body>
```

Ругается на закрывающий h1, соответственно ничего не выводится. В чем дело?

Comment: JSX не поддерживается браузерами.

Comment: jsx без препроцессинга тоже нету. Вы боретесь с ветряными мельницами вместо того чтобы настроить препроцессинг

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот эти "теги" которые Вы передаете в ReactDOM.render, это не html. Это [**JSX**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html). JSX - это не реакт. JSX - это такое расширение javascript. Обычно JSX транслируется в нормальный js на этапе сборки-препроцессинга.

**Во-первых**, настройте все-таки нормальную сборку лучше.

**Во-вторых**, React [можно использовать и без jsx](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html), это не очень удобно и мало кто так делает.

**В-третьих**, можно организовать трансляцию jsx в js "на лету", прямо на клиенте. Обычно jsx в es5-js транслируется на сервере, на этапе сборки с помощью [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). У Babel на всякий случай есть [standalone-сборка](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) для работы на клиенте. Это для очень упорных парней, но вариант вроде бы тоже рабочий.

Comment: А с JSX нужен обязательно Node JS?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, нет, смотри пункт 3. Но пытаясь обойтись без ноды, Вы себе больше проблем прибавляете чем решаете. Современный фронтенд сильно завязан на конфигурацию и сервер сайд препроцессинг.

Comment: Ладно, понял, спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: @TimurMusharapov ссылку на standalone-бабель добавил

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, кстати, не лишне будет уточнить, если Вы еще не поняли, нода обычно нужна только на машине разработчика/билд машине. На собственно сервере где гоняет бэкенд вашего приложения ей по большому счету делать нечего. Так что если проблема с тем, что доступа к бэку нету, это не проблема. Также для настройки писать код под ноду тоже обычно не надо. Кроме какой-нибудь конфигурации для вебпака, которая тупо json.